# Makefile multiple targets in sub-directories

Tags: makefile

***Hi!***

I started messing with makefiles a few days ago, so I gave myself a exercise to learn as well as making my life easier.
I basically want to read the directory the makefile is in (root) and use [luamin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/luamin) to compress the file as much as possible before I deploy it to our server. But I would like to have it as flexible as possible, so depending on where said file is in the directory it should mirror it to the server.

So if it finds a file in a sub folder called `home` it should create a new folder with the same name with the compressed file within. I have gotten the compression of files in the root folder working as well as creation of the directories where the files should reside.

```
objs = $(wildcard *.lua)
dirs = $(wildcard */)

compress: $(objs)
    mkdir -p .build
    luamin -f $(objs) > .build/$(objs)
    mkdir .build/$(dirs)

clean:
    rm -rf ./.build

deploy: .build
    cp ./.build/* ~
```

Comment: So if the directory contained `foo/bar.lua`, then you would like to create a directory with `mkdir .build/foo` and then create the compressed file with `luamin -f foo/bar > .build/foo/bar.lua`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That way I do not have to worry about they being copied to the wrong place and just have to give one path, the root destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **GNU make**, there are several features that really help to do what you want. Warning: this works if and only if your file names **do not contain spaces**:

```
srcfiles := $(shell find . -path .build -prune -o -type f -name '*.lua' -print)
dstfiles := $(addprefix .build/,$(srcfiles))

.PHONY: compress clean deploy

compress: $(dstfiles)

$(dstfiles): .build/%: %
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    luamin -f $< > $@

clean:
    rm -rf ./.build

deploy: .build
    cp ./.build/* ~
```

Explanation:

1. The `shell` make function is used to run the `find` command that searches all subdirectories, except `.build`, for `*.lua` files. The result is assigned to the `srcfiles` make variable.
2. The `addprefix` make function is used to add the `.build/` prefix to all words of the `srcfiles` make variable and assign the result to the `dstfiles` make variable.
3. The `compress` target is the first (real) target in the Makefile. It is thus the default goal that gets run when invoking just `make`. It is the same as invoking `make compress`. The `compress` target is declared as phony. This tells make that it is not a real file, just like `clean` and `deploy`. The `compress` target depends on all destination files. If one is missing or older than its corresponding source file, it must be rebuilt.
4. The make [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) `$(dstfiles): .build/%: %...` declares a generic rule where each destination file (`.build/./foo/bar/baz.lua`) depends on the corresponding source file (`./foo/bar/baz.lua`). The recipe creates the destination directory (`./foo/bar/`), computed thanks to the `dir` make function. Then, it applies the `luamin` command. The recipe makes use of the `$@` and `$<` [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Comment: I don't have GNU installed and have never heard of it before. So I get the paths working but I can't do the `destfiles` variable to work. I tried the `cut` command but it only does it to the first element. Is there a way to loop through elements in a variable like this similar to `addprefix`?

Comment: What make do you use and what version of it?

Comment: I see now that when I print the version I have GNU installed, it says it uses GNU Make 4.1 built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.

Comment: OK, so, what's wrong with the `dstfiles` (not `destfiles`) variable? What happens exactly?

Comment: It seems like the issue was that it converted the tabs to spaces and therefore didn't recognize the file.